# I'm trying to customize a seekbar, but it's not working

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this image of the seekbar that I want to build:
[image]

But my seekbar is looking like this:

[image]

My seekbar has no transparency and I can not make it thinner.
How can I do this?

Here are the codes:
Seekbar:

```
                <SeekBar
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:alpha="0.75"
                    android:max="25"
                    android:min="7"
                    android:progress="1"
                    android:splitTrack="false"
                    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_seek_bar_settings"
                    android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar_settins" />
```

Thumb:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp" />

            <solid android:color="@color/color_primary_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Progress:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/color_primary"
                android:endColor="@color/color_primary"/>
            <size
                android:width="1dp"
                android:height="2dp"
                 />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/color_primary"
                    android:endColor="@color/color_primary" />
                <size
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:height="2dp"
                    />
                <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I need help getting it as close to the first image as possible. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello in *drawable/progress_seek_bar_settings* transform

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
```

in

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
      android:height="3dp"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
    >
```

**UPDATE**

drawable/thumb_seekbar_settins.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <size
                android:height="20dp"
                android:width="20dp" />
            <solid android:color="#ebeb" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

drawable/progress_seek_bar_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:height="3dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ebeb"
                android:endColor="#ebeb"/>
            <size
                android:width="1dp"
                android:height="2dp"
                />
            <corners android:radius="3dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:height="3dp"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
        >
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#ebeb"
                    android:endColor="#ebeb" />
                <size
                    android:width="1dp"
                    android:height="2dp"
                    />
                <corners android:radius="3dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    >
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.75"
        android:max="100"
        android:min="7"
        android:progress="1"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_seek_bar_settings"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb_seekbar_settins" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to point you need to add height to progress too, sorry